# Chrome cleartype

Tags: windows, google-chrome

Am running latest Chrome (44.0.2403.130 m) on Windows 10.

Text in the Windows Edge and Internet Explorer look crisp, while text in Chrome doesn't.

Check the magnified images below to see what I mean, left is on Chrome, right is on Edge browser.

Is there any way I can have the text more readable in Chrome as well?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix this is to go to `chrome://settings/fonts` and play with the settings until you find something that suits your taste.

Also, if your desktop is at a 125% or 150% zoom, this problem may occur. To solve this, you can try going to `chrome://flags/#distance-field-text` and enabling distance field text.